# Why can't i find my Apex Class to fire an action in process builder?

Tags: apex, process-builder

Why can't i find my apex class in process builder?

I've set up my conditions and i'm trying to fire an Apex class. Why can't i find my class or any class in the Apex Class list?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. In order for one to find your apex class or method an annotation must be added to your method.

Here's some info on invocable methods:

> Use the InvocableMethod annotation to identify methods that can be run
>   as invocable actions. Invocable methods are called with the REST API
>   and used to invoke a single Apex method. Invocable methods have
>   dynamic input and output values and support describe calls.

[Source: SalesForce Developer Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm)

Comment: Something you might want to be aware of with invocable methods: If you re-save your class, the step with the Apex will disappear from the process and will need to be re-added.